Инициализатор конструтора this
CS8862 Конструктор, объявленный в типе со списком параметров, должен содержать инициализатор конструктора "this"
public class Person()
{
    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Я честно не понимаю, может я такой тупой?

В объявлении класса не ставится (). Заменить Person() на Person

боже мой, какая же очевидная ошибка, я такой рассеянный в последнее время, спасибо большое за помощь

У Вас скобочки лишние в объявлении класса:
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
         Name = name;
         Age = age;
     }
     public int Age { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }


Да, точно, бывает такие банальные ошибки допускаю, хотя вроде и понимаю что-то в dotnet, а подсветка как на зло на конструкторе, да и ошибка о конструкторе
